# PC Lint Error while using templates

Tags: c++, templates, lint, pc-lint

When I run the PC lint application for the below mentioned code I get errors:

The errors for line (1) are

> Error 129: declaration expected, identifier '__created' ignored
>   Error 10: Expecting identifier or other declarator
>   Error 129: declaration expected, identifier 'typename' ignored

```
template<typename T,UINT32 capacity> //(1)
class A
{
  public:
    A();
    T *alloc();
    T *free( T *ptr);
  //Private members
  private:
    T *m_headPtr;
    T m_pool[capacity];
}
```

How can I get rid of the errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding +fcp to the build command solved my problem

Comment: Yes, this tells lint to great all files as cpp files. You should use standard file extensions, though.

Answer (score 1):

Save the file as a C++ file with the correct ending or tell lint to treat it as such, currently, it seems to be treated as a C file.

Comment: The file is saved as a c++ file(.hpp) but still the error persists. Meanwhile how do i force the file to be treated as a c++ file in lint?